# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I am just experimenting and having fun with Python 2.7 and I'm trying to write a quadratic equation solver. I had it working when the radicand is positive, but when it's negative im getting an error. even after this if else statement. it also doesnt work with big numbers. thanks for the help.

```
import math
a = raw_input("a = ")
b = raw_input("b = ")
c = raw_input("c = ")
float(a)
float(b)
float(c)
radicand = ((b**2)-4*a*c)
if radicand >= 0:
    print(((0-b) + math.sqrt((b**2)-4*a*c))/(2*a))
    print(((0-b) - math.sqrt((b**2)-4*a*c))/(2*a))
else:
    print "Imaginary Radical"
```

when i replace (b**2)-4*a*c with radicand i get an invalid syntax error and print is highlighted in red. 
the error message says 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
thanks again for any insight you can provide...

Answer (score 5):

You should replace:

```
float(a)
```

with:

```
a = float(a)
```

and similarly for the other variables.

The statement `float(a)` doesn't actually turn `a` *into* a `float`, it simply casts it, as per the following transcript:

```
>>> a = raw_input("a? ")
a? 4.5

>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>

>>> float(a)
4.5

>>> type(a)
<type 'str'>

>>> a = float(a)

>>> type(a)
<type 'float'>
```

You can see that the type of `a` is *still* `str` immediately after performing `float(a)` but, when you execute thew assignment `a = float(a)`, the type becomes `float`.

Answer (score 0):

the statement `float(a)` returns the float value of the string a. But if you do not assign to any other variable, then float(a) holds only for that particular line. In the next line, a is a string. So, assign the float value to a variable, say a itself.

```
a=float(a)
```

This will make `a` a float