# Python Create a New Column with Applying a Formula

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import scipy.stats as st
```

My input dataframe;

```
ServiceLevel  CoverPeriod  ParameterA  ParameterB  ParameterC  DailyForecast
0.95              4           0.07        1.2          0.9           0.22
0.97              4           0.08        1.21         0.88          0.35
0.92              5           0.08        1.1          0.87          0.86
```

I want to calculate Safety Stock with this code;

```
df['SafetyStock_Test'] = st.norm.ppf(df["ServiceLevel"])*np.sqrt(df["CoverPeriod"]/7)*[(df["ParameterA"])+(df["ParameterB"])*(((df["DailyForecast"])*7)**df["ParameterC"])]
```

But I got this error messages;

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'float' and
>   'str'

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: import scipy.stats as st

Comment: Check the `dtypes` of `df` and assign some of the terms of your equation to variables to aid in readability (and check for imbalanced brackets etc). Also try isolate the error. Does this give the same error `((df["DailyForecast"])*7)**df["ParameterC"]`?

Comment: Also I think your `[]` should be `()` around the long term after the `sqrt`

Answer (score 0):

To resolve your issue, ensure that all columns have the right format.

```py
df = df.apply(pd.to_nuneric)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be an error regarding the type of value for calculation. As it should be `float` value instead `str`.

Try using `float()` for values to calculate.

for example:  `float(df["ParameterC"]))`

For the reference regarding your error, check the [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056264/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-or-pow-str-and-int)

Answer (score 0):

The last part of your formula is

`(((df["DailyForecast"])*7)**df["ParameterC"])`

`((df["DailyForecast"])*7)` and `df["ParameterC"]` are the operands for the ** or pow() operator.
See https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html .

The pow() operator is called like this: pow(a,b) where a and b are numbers. In your code either a (the first operand) or b (the second operand) is a string. That is why the error message

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'float' and
>   'str'

occurs.

You should check if either `((df["DailyForecast"])*7)` or `df["ParameterC"]` is a string.

Comment: `print(type(df["ParameterC"]))` will yield `pd.Series` cause that's the obj type. You want to look at the series `dtype` instead

Comment: Thank you rafaelc. I removed that part of the answer because it leads astray.